# Should I avoid using style like `for k, v in dict_sample.items()`?

Tags: programming-practices, python, readability

Today I was viewing my colleague's code and I saw a function like this:

```
def manager_skill_tree_func(*args, **kwargs):
    """# manage_skill_tree: Initialize the manage skill tree
    """
    skill_tree0 = {}
    head = []
    tree_skill_list = {}
    manage_skill = globals()['manage_skill']

    for k, v in manage_skill.iteritems():
        if not k in skill_tree0:
            skill_tree0[k] = {}
        if v['tree'] not in tree_skill_list:
            tree_skill_list[v['tree']] = set([k])
        else:
            tree_skill_list[v['tree']].add(k)
        pre_k_list = v['pre_skill']
        if not pre_k_list:
            head.append(k)
        for pre_k in pre_k_list:
            pre_k = int(pre_k)
            if not pre_k in skill_tree0:
                skill_tree0[pre_k] = {}
            skill_tree0[pre_k][k] = skill_tree0[k]

    # Rest of the function is omitted here
```

There are lots of readability issues in this piece of code, but my attentions was mostly draw by the `for k, v in manage_skill.itermitems()` statement. This kind of statement was heavily used in the project, it seems that my colleague doesn't like to specify what kind of keys and values they are obtaining from the `dict`.

For me, I'll use something like `for index, arg_dict in dict_sample.iteritems()` if the key is a number and the value is another dict, and `for employee_tuple in employee_info` to specify the item type I'll get tuple from the list.

I think names should offer some meaning, in the statement `for pre_k in pre_k_list:` of above code, I got no information about what kind of data this `pre_k` is, except that it's not called `k` again.

I would use `for k, v in sample_dict.items()` or `for i in sample_list` only when the structure was already mentioned and is really obvious, like:

```
import random
sample_dict = {}
for i in xrange(10):
    sample_dict[i] = random.choice([1,2,3])

for k,v in sample_dict.items():
    sample_dict[k] = k/v
```

What's your opinion on `for k,v in unknown_structure_dict.iteritems()`?

---

PS: As an extra gift, here is a pylint evaluation of a large file for @jonrsharpe.

A weak defend for this disaster score:

1. Project lasts for years
2. Written by plenty of programmers(from novice to veteran)
3. Lots of requirement changes, lots of hot-fix.
4. Some modules or classes are loaded at running time.

Anyway, enjoy this:

```
+-----------------------------+------------+
|message id                   |occurrences |
+=============================+============+
|bad-whitespace               |1572        |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|bad-continuation             |479         |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|line-too-long                |303         |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|unused-argument              |99          |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|invalid-name                 |95          |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|no-member                    |65          |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|missing-docstring            |32          |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|redefined-outer-name         |31          |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|trailing-whitespace          |14          |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|unused-variable              |8           |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|global-variable-not-assigned |6           |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|fixme                        |6           |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|unnecessary-semicolon        |5           |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|bare-except                  |3           |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|eval-used                    |2           |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|too-many-locals              |1           |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|too-many-lines               |1           |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|superfluous-parens           |1           |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|multiple-statements          |1           |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|empty-docstring              |1           |
+-----------------------------+------------+



Global evaluation
-----------------
Your code has been rated at -47.74/10
```

Comment: You're asking about the names k and v, right? Not about the for... .iteritems() construct?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, yes

Comment: Meaningful variable names, or no pizza. Bad programmer! Bad!! No pizza!

Comment: This question comes dangerously close to being a rant in disguise ("I'm curious if other people feel like I do" and "___ sucks, am I right?" on [_What types of questions should I avoid asking?_](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). At the least, I'd consider it a leading question.

Comment: I think the only reasonable solution to this is to bring it up during code review "for k,v ... let's name this instead something more transparent like for id,name or something!??"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree with you, and e.g. `pylint` would complain about those names too (albeit purely on a length basis).

`for k, v in ...` gives the reader no helpful information about what they should be expecting to get from the dictionary, which makes the subsequent code harder to follow. For example, it's only at `if v['tree']...` that you find out that the value is (presumably!) a dictionary. This requires you to look at the code where the dictionary is built to figure out what should be in it, and means you cannot just read and understand the function on its own (especially as the docstring is useless).

Even something as simple as:

```
for skill_name, skill_dict in manage_skill.iteritems():
```

would make the code clearer.

Comment: Note: if the method were a *generic* traversal method, then `k`, `v` would be pretty natural names. It all depends on context. In fact, I have the feeling that the method is doing too much, and a generic traversal method could be extracted from it. The fact that the OP sees stuff like "all over the code" seems to indicate that there is some underlying structure to the dicts that is replicated across many different functions, and could be extracted into a library of generic traversal functions. Or possibly, the dicts should actually be objects, responsible for managing their own traversal.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's a very good point

Comment: 19 lines of code for one function the OP posted with a comment "rest of the function omitted here", that's a lot for one function, especially for a language as expressive as Python. I feel there's a `SkillTree` abstraction missing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Most of my colleagues don't use pylint. The code was a huge project write by different levels of programers in years. So as it doesn't broke. People let it go. I'll append a pylint evaluation of one large files(thousands of lines).

Comment: @Zen well I wouldn't expect you to fix everything at once!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, enjoy the pylint result appended in the answer!

Comment: @Zen wow, I didn't know `pylint` scores *could* go negative! You might want to look into how you can (slowly!) move towards better code throughout the project, e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/135651/110531

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it's painful when reading these code. They were not designed for reading. All one-time use stuff. I even have impulse to kill myself when read these code. Gee.